# Sharepoint 2007 Count Modifications View

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to create a list view that contains a column for how many times a document has been modified? I would also like a "Total Modifications" value that sums the modifications from that column.

I am new to sharepoint. If this is possible, where should I start looking for the information on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on versioning control in the document library settings and edit the views to include [version]. This will only work going forwards of course.

Comment: If I do sum([version]) I only get the count of the rows on the page I am on which are documents 1-200. When I go to the next page (201-400), the count changes to reflect that page.

Comment: do you want the total modifications for the entire document library? I understood you to mean the modifications to the document itself. In which case, a simple SPD workflow would suffice